# SQL query to calculate current and past month billing usage

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, billing

I have a hourly based billing system where I generate invoice on 1st of the month. The below query returns total hours and total usage between the given start date/end date.

If offering is created in between a month it should be added in the 1st of next month. Currently I am able to get usage from 1st - Last Day of the month.

Eg. If user has purchase item on 15th Jan and invoice to be generated on 1st Feb I need to get those 15 days usage as well as 1st Feb - 30th Feb advance usage. The invoice will be generated monthly until the `deleted_at` is null

```
select
  `total_price`,
  (
    GREATEST(
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(
        HOUR,
        GREATEST(
          created_at,
          $startDate
        ),
        IFNULL(deleted_at, $endDate),
      ) + 1,
      0
    ) * total_price
  ) AS usage_price,
  (
    GREATEST(
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(
        HOUR,
        GREATEST( 
          created_at,
          $startDate
        ),
        IFNULL(deleted_at, $endDate)
      ) + 1,
      0
    )
  ) AS usage_hour
from
  `offerings`
```

Here I am Passing `$startDate` as `now()->startOfMonth()` and `$endDate` as `now()->endOfMonth` from Carbon library

The table is pretty simple and straight forward

| ID | name | total_price | created_at | deleted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | OFFER1 | 100 | 15-08-2022 12:00:00 | NULL |

**Expected Result:**

If the invoice is to be generated based on the above db record with total price 100 on 1st Aug 2022,
usage_price column should return 360hrs(15-July-22 to 31-July-2022) + 720hrs(01-Aug-22 to 30-Aug-22) * total_price = 36,000 + 72,000 = **1,08,000**

Again when the invoice generates on next cycle i.e 1st Sept 2022 it should calculate from 1st Sept to 31st Sept unless new record is not created in Aug
Please let me know in case you need more info about the DB structure

Comment: can you provide some sample data and the expected result? - I can't get my head around it :-)

Comment: I have updated my question with one row in my DB structure. Assuming that we have only 1 offering created in offerings table. I need to calculate total usage hours. I have updated my question with expected result

Comment: the OFFER1 was created in August (according to the table) so why are you calculating anything before that date (July?) And if the offer started in mid-August how can be included on invoice generated Aug 1st? I really can't get it :-)

Comment: Regular cycle will be from 1-31 of every month but in case if anything is created midway it wont be calculated in the invoice, so thats the reason I need to include past 15 days in the next month invoice

Comment: Ok, just to clarify things based on example data. A customer starts the OFFER1 on 2022-08-15 at the price 100 per hour. On 2022-09-01 his FIRST invoice is about to be billed. The billing should include the whole period 2022-09-01 to 2022-09-30 (upfront billing for 30 days) PLUS 2022-08-15 to 2022-08-31 (17 days)? And the next month a new invoice is generated on 2022-10-01 only for the period 2022-10-01 to 2022-10-31 (31 days) - is it right?

Comment: Yes right, its a whole cycle and when the next new invoice generates on 01-10-2022 it should check if there is new offer created in between in sept month. This one is continues. In short it should generate upfront as well as check if there is something created in the previous month and add it to invoice to be generated on 1st of the month